# How to use the delete method in Devise for sign out? rails route failure (performing get)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, rails-engines

So I have built a mountable Engine and added devise for authentication:

And for some reason the :delete method on links is performing a get here is the relevant code:

**Index.html.erb**

`<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>`

**Config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

**Routes**

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

**Error**

```
No route matches [GET] "/my_engine/users/sign_out"
```

changing `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get` fix's the problem and allows me to sign_out however this is the wrong way to do things a signout should be a delete and would love to get this working if anyone has any ideas

**Additional Info (Gems + Ruby Version + Actual HTML displayed on page for logout link)**

I am using `ruby-1.9.3-p398`

this is the html displayed on page for layout link

```
<a class="navbar-link" data-method="delete" href="/antithetical/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>
```

and the gems:

```
Using rake (10.1.1)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activesupport (4.0.2)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.2)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.2)
Using activemodel (4.0.2)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Using activerecord (4.0.2)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
Using orm_adapter (0.5.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.2)
Using warden (1.2.3)
Using devise (3.2.2)
Using bundler (1.5.2)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.10.1)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using rails (4.0.2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out that engines (possibly just `--mountable`) do not include jquery to do things like `:delete` or `:post` so my fix was  to include `jquery-rails`

**engine.gemspec**

```
+ s.add_dependency "jquery-rails"
```

**app/assets/javascripts/engine/application.js**

```
+//= require jquery
+//= require jquery_ujs
+//= require_tree .
```

Comment: @Oskar I didn't have to require 'jquery-rails' inside of the engine.rb as far as I know this should be automatically loaded just like in a rails app?

Comment: Not for me. Maybe you are using `jquery-rails` in your app so it dosen't need to be loaded in the engine? My engine where a dashboard with it's own web interface whereas my main app where just an API, so I didn't use `jquery-rails` there. In that setup I needed to require `jquery-rails` in the engine in order to get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
I just add:

#### #layouts/application.html.haml

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```